# Impersonation step and elevated account with password close to expiring

Tags: 2010, workflow, impersonation

I have a workflow on SP 2010 with impersonation step. The account that created the workflow probably will have the password expired in the next few days. This will surely cause the workflow to stop working as explained on this forum several times.

What is the best/safest procedure to fix this matter? I was thinking of using a specifically created system account with password set to never expires, log in with that account and re-publish the workflow, would that be enough?

Comment: Your thinking is correct. Creating a dedicated account specifically for the workflow impersonation is the right thing to do.

Comment: Then when I re-publish the workflow everything will go down smoothly?

Comment: When you re-publish the workflow with a new account then all new instances of the workflow will run under your new account. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

`Impersonation step` is not asking to add password of system account. So may be it will not cause the problem in workflow.

But if problem is there, set password `to never expire`, it will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: The point is that we cannot set the password of the current account to never expire and we would like to simply have another account re-issue the workflow